# How to correct "corrupt and unarchivable nib"?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa, xib

I am writing a macOS app in Swift4. I'm targeting macOS 10.9, so I'm using xibs instead of storyboards.

When I try to run and open the nib via showing the window, it logs an error:

```
-[NSIBObjectData initWithCoder:]: corrupt and unarchivable nib file
-[MyWindowController loadWindow]: failed to load window nib file '/Users/toadzky/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-cdudiyhqvfaauudsignqhtkqlfeu/Build/Products/Debug/My App.app/Contents/Resources/MyWindow.nib'.
```

The file is a xib, so i'm not sure if it's just an outdated error message. I'm subclassing `NSWindowController` and using the `init(windowNibName:)` constructor for my window controller.

I've tried restarting Xcode, cleaning and rebuilding the project, modifying the xib so xcode will rewrite it, etc. I haven't re-created it from scratch because it's a fairly complex view, and it's time consuming to redo so I'm hoping there's an alternative solution.

### Update

I rebuilt the entire XIB from scratch, no copy-paste since I couldn't be sure what was wrong. Everything worked fine until I added some custom formatters using interface builder. Then it broke in the same way. I took them off and it worked again.

Two hours later, I added the custom formatters back and it works fine.

I'm leaving the question open in the hopes that someone will be able to provide some troubleshooting advice for when Xcode decides to arbitrarily not work for a while.

Comment: Some ideas: View the XIB as Source Code, do you see any rubbish?. Copy and paste the window to recreate the XIB.

Comment: yep, take a look at the XML and see if anything unusual... wrong identifiers, bad code, conflict in file... anything..

Comment: i've looked through the xml. it validates as xml, but it's 1200+ lines, so it's unlikely a cursory inspection will solve it.

Comment: yes, updated to reflect that.

Comment: I found this problem today and it was one of the formatter for a text field. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in your init method you are initializing the super class and returning self.